# how to convert days in decimal number to actual days using Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I want to show in my html page like:

```
var days = 187.89808080;
<div>
  <span>Showing last {days} days</span>
</div>
```

its displaying:
`Showing last 187.89808080 days`, instead is there a way in moment.js i can convert those days into months, for ex: 187 days equivalent to 6 months?

thanks

Comment: What would you expect the output to be? Do you mean something like "187 days, 21 hours and 33 minutes"?

Comment: the expected output in days only

Comment: So what *would* be the expected output? Just "187"? I'm finding it hard to understand what you mean by "actual days" and "human readable number" - 187 is more readable than 187.89808080 but loses a lot of precision. If you just need to get the integer value, that's not really date or moment-related at all.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: updated the question. thanks

Comment: It's still somewhat unclear - "The expected output is in days only." seems to contradict an expected result of "6 months" as that *isn't* in days only - it's in months. Do you mean you want a result in years, months and days, but you don't care about values *smaller* than a day? Unfortunately things like "6 months" aren't fixed lengths of time". For example "28 days" might be a month, or it might not be, depending on which month it is. (If you have two dates, you can work out the difference between those in years, months and days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the number of days, then only round down the number, you don't need a complex library for that.

`parseInt(days)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax